# Verify (with static_assert) that tuple types follow some order (stateful compile-time check)

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, c++14, variadic-templates

For some serialization application in a relatively old software, I have types that look like this:

```
using T = boost::tuple<
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<uint32_t, 0>, std::vector<int>>,
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<uint32_t, 1>, std::vector<double>>
    >;
T events;
```

These constant numbers are `static constexpr` and represent some database table, and the vector is of some storage type (details not important).

To make this "kind of" type safe, and make everything work together for the future, I need to ensure that a user who adds another type to the tuple follows the serial number. So another element **should be this**:

```
using T = boost::tuple<
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<uint32_t, 0>, std::vector<int>>,
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<uint32_t, 1>, std::vector<double>>,
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<uint32_t, 2>, std::vector<float>>
    >;
T events;
```

This is **wrong and should not compile**:

```
using T = boost::tuple<
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<uint32_t, 0>, std::vector<int>>,
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<uint32_t, 1>, std::vector<double>>,
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<uint32_t, 1>, std::vector<float>>
    >;
T events;
```

**My solution** has failed so far, and I'd appreciate someone's input on this:

```
template <typename Tuple>
struct tuple_assert;

template <typename... Ts>
struct tuple_assert<boost::tuple<Ts...>> {
  static constexpr void verify() {
    __verify<std::integral_constant<uint32_t, 0>, Ts...>();
  }

  static constexpr void __verify() {}

  template <typename Count, typename Pair>
  static constexpr void __verify() {
        static_assert(std::is_same<typename Pair::first_type, Count>::value, "");
  }

  template <typename Count, typename Pair, typename... Ts2>
  static constexpr void __verify() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<typename Pair::first_type, Count>::value, "");

    __verify<std::integral_constant<uint32_t, Pair::first_type::value + 1>,
             Ts...>();
  }
};
```

So what you see up there is that I created a state (`Count`) and I'm increasing the count at every iteration. But this somehow reaches the wrong state and the `static_assert()` fires when I use it with this call:

```
tuple_assert<T>::verify(); // `T` is the type I mentioned at the very beginning
```

[See my solution that doesn't work online.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2afcf9f04fd670f9)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should the numbers be in sequence or is any order allowed as long as they are unique? Can you skip a number?

Comment: Start with fixing a typo in the last `__verify`, where you probably meant to expand `Ts2...`, not `Ts...`

Comment: @Albjenow They should be in sequence and they should start from 0. Starting from 0 is not important because no one is gonna change that.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki It's not a typo. It would overshadow the class template type.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist You misunderstood what I said

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Oh, you're right there. Sorry about that.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist So what is the point of "storing" the index in the first place? It could be deduced from the position when needed. Instead it increases the memory foot-print of the tuple type unnecessarily.

Comment: @Albjenow That index is some definition that's used elsewhere. It has to be in the serialization and deserialization of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code. First one is in this line, a typo in template argument list expansion:

```
__verify<std::integral_constant<uint32_t, Pair::first_type::value + 1>,
         Ts...>();
```

It should be:

```
__verify<std::integral_constant<uint32_t, Pair::first_type::value + 1>,
         Ts2...>();
```

But sadly it won't fix it. `boost::tuple` has some strange typedefs inside with some `nulltype_t`. Changing it to `std::tuple` still won't fix it as your `__verify` function call is ambiguous. So instead here are my solutions.

## `std::tuple`

```
template<unsigned V, class T, class ...Args>
struct verify_types {
    static constexpr bool value = V == T::first_type::value && verify_types<V+1, Args...>::value;
};

template<unsigned V, class T>
struct verify_types<V, T> {
    static constexpr bool value = V == T::first_type::value;
};

template<class T>
struct verify_tuple : std::false_type {};

template<class ...Args>
struct verify_tuple<std::tuple<Args...>> : verify_types<0, Args...>{};
```

## `boost::tuple`

This one is a bit more convoluted.

```
template<unsigned V, class T, class ...Args>
struct verify_types {
    static constexpr bool value = V == T::first_type::value && verify_types<V+1, Args...>::value;
};

template<unsigned V, class ...Args>
struct verify_types<V, boost::tuples::null_type, Args...> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template<unsigned V, class T>
struct verify_types<V, T> {
    static constexpr bool value = V == T::first_type::value;
};

template<class T>
struct verify_tuple : std::false_type {};

template<class ...Args>
struct verify_tuple<boost::tuple<Args...>> : verify_types<0, Args...>{};
```

Notice handling of `boost::tuples::null_type`. It is caused by the fact that `boost::tuple` was created before C++11 and variadic templates.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/3-WUmD)

Comment: Thank you, but I need this for `boost::tuple`, not `std::tuple`... It doesn't work the same because `boost` has some functions missing.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist updated for `boost::tuple`. But it is cumbersome and outdated in implementation so I suggest switching to `std`

Comment: May I suggest that you list both solutions for `std::tuple` and `boost::tuple`? Both are valuable!

Answer (score 1):

Is too late to play?

Sorry but... why don't you simply use template deduction?

Something as

```
template <typename>
struct check_tuple;

template <template <typename...> class Tpl, std::uint32_t ... Is,
          typename ... Ts>
struct check_tuple<Tpl<
   std::pair<std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, Is>, Ts>...>>
   : public std::is_same<
      std::integer_sequence<std::uint32_t, Is...>,
      std::make_integer_sequence<std::uint32_t, sizeof...(Is)>>
 { };
```

<s>Observe that the use of a template-template parameter permit to use it with `std::tuple` and also `boost::tuple`.</s> [wrong: see following EDIT]

The following is a full compiling C++14 example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

using T1 = std::tuple<
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, 0>, std::vector<int>>,
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, 1>, std::vector<double>>,
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, 2>, std::vector<float>>
    >;

using T2 = std::tuple<
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, 0>, std::vector<int>>,
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, 1>, std::vector<double>>,
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, 1>, std::vector<float>>
    >;

template <typename>
struct check_tuple;

template <template <typename...> class Tpl, std::uint32_t ... Is,
          typename ... Ts>
struct check_tuple<Tpl<
   std::pair<std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, Is>, Ts>...>>
   : public std::is_same<
      std::integer_sequence<std::uint32_t, Is...>,
      std::make_integer_sequence<std::uint32_t, sizeof...(Is)>>
 { };

int main()
 {
   static_assert( check_tuple<T1>::value == true, "!" );
   static_assert( check_tuple<T2>::value == false, "!" );
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

I was wrong: `boost::tuple` isn't defined as `std::tuple`, receiving a variadic list of template types, but with a fixed number (10, but should be possible modify it) of type template parameter, defaulted to `boost::tuples::null_type`.

So, by example,

```
using T1 = boost::tuple<
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, 0>, std::vector<int>>,
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, 1>, std::vector<double>>,
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, 2>, std::vector<float>>
    >;
```

has three `std::pair` and seven `boost::tuples::null_type`.

In other words, T1 is

```
using T1 = boost::tuple<
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, 0>, std::vector<int>>,
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, 1>, std::vector<double>>,
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, 2>, std::vector<float>>,
    boost::tuples::null_type,
    boost::tuples::null_type,
    boost::tuples::null_type,
    boost::tuples::null_type,
    boost::tuples::null_type,
    boost::tuples::null_type,
    boost::tuples::null_type
    >;
```

This break my preceding solution because

```
template <template <typename...> class Tpl, std::uint32_t ... Is,
          typename ... Ts>
struct check_tuple<Tpl<
   std::pair<std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, Is>, Ts>...>>
```

doesn't intercept the seven finals `boost::tuples::null_type`.

The best I can imagine, to solve this problem, is a `boost::tuple` versus `std::tuple` type conversion that remove the `boost::tuples::null_type` types.

I mean

```
template <typename T>
struct get_tuple
 { using type = std::tuple<T>; } ;

template <>
struct get_tuple<boost::tuples::null_type>
 { using type = std::tuple<>; };

template <typename ... Ts>
auto convert_tuple (boost::tuple<Ts...>)
   -> decltype( std::tuple_cat(std::declval<typename get_tuple<Ts>::type>()...) );
```

Now `check_tuple` can be rewritten as follows

```
template <typename T,
          typename = decltype(convert_tuple(std::declval<T>()))>
struct check_tuple;

template <typename BT, std::uint32_t ... Is, typename ... Ts>
struct check_tuple<BT, std::tuple<
   std::pair<std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, Is>, Ts>...>>
   : public std::is_same<
      std::integer_sequence<std::uint32_t, Is...>,
      std::make_integer_sequence<std::uint32_t, sizeof...(Is)>>
 { };
```

The following is a full compiling C++14 example using `boost::tuple`

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include "boost/tuple/tuple.hpp"

using T1 = boost::tuple<
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, 0>, std::vector<int>>,
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, 1>, std::vector<double>>,
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, 2>, std::vector<float>>
    >;

using T2 = boost::tuple<
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, 0>, std::vector<int>>,
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, 1>, std::vector<double>>,
    std::pair<std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, 1>, std::vector<float>>
>;

template <typename T>
struct get_tuple
 { using type = std::tuple<T>; } ;

template <>
struct get_tuple<boost::tuples::null_type>
 { using type = std::tuple<>; };

template <typename ... Ts>
auto convert_tuple (boost::tuple<Ts...>)
   -> decltype( std::tuple_cat(std::declval<typename get_tuple<Ts>::type>()...) );


template <typename T,
          typename = decltype(convert_tuple(std::declval<T>()))>
struct check_tuple;

template <typename BT, std::uint32_t ... Is, typename ... Ts>
struct check_tuple<BT, std::tuple<
   std::pair<std::integral_constant<std::uint32_t, Is>, Ts>...>>
   : public std::is_same<
      std::integer_sequence<std::uint32_t, Is...>,
      std::make_integer_sequence<std::uint32_t, sizeof...(Is)>>
 { };

int main()
 {
   static_assert( check_tuple<T1>::value == true, "!" );
   static_assert( check_tuple<T2>::value == false, "!" );
 }
```

Comment: Very nice! You get my upvote ;-) . I wonder whether this works with `boost::tuple`? I'll probably try it out later.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist - I don't have a platform with boost installed but... why not? I've used `template <typename ...> class Tpl` exactly to intercept every template type that receive, as template argument, a variadic list of types.

Comment: It actually doesn't work with `boost::tuple`. I'm trying to figure out why. I'm not familiar with some of the templates you used, so I'm not sure how long this'll take. If you can try it (even later in the day) that would be great.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist - I'm surprised: as far I know, `boost::tuple` is defined exactly as `std::tuple`: receiving a variadic list of types... I'll try to verify in a platform with boosts installed.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist - no, I was wrong: `boost::tuple` is different from `std::tuple`: doesn't receive a variadic list of arguments but exactly 10 template arguments, defaulted to `boost::tuples::null_type`; so `T1` has three `std::pair` followed by seven `boost::tuples::null_type`. It's a problem... but I have an half idea... give me some time to elaborate.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist - solved adding a `boost::tuple` to `std::tuple` type converter; answer improved (see after "-- EDIT --")

Comment: The solution for std::tuple is quite nice, but for boost::tuple is a little messy. I'll use your solution for std and the other solution for boost. Thanks for this nice code ;-)